# How do I execute JS XHR responses in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

What I'm looking for looks like this in jQuery:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
  }
});
...
$("#my_form").submit({
  $.post($(this).attr("action", $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
  return false;
});
```

Then, when my server returns some Javascript (the Accept-header bit), jQuery executes it (that last "script" parameter).

I'm trying to get the same effect in Dojo.  My best guess is:

```
form = dojo.byId("my_form")
form.onsubmit = function() {
  dojo.xhrGet({
    url: form.action,
    form: form,
    handleAs: "javascript"
  })
}
```

The `handleAs: "javascript"` should cause Dojo to execute the response as JS.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to set the header so that my web server (a `respond_to do |format|` block in Rails) knows what to return.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer is:

```
form = dojo.byId("my_form")
  form.onsubmit = function() {
  dojo.xhrGet({
    url: form.action,
    form: form,
    handleAs: "javascript",
    headers: { "Accept": "text/javascript" }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about dojo myself but I do know that phiggins (lead dojo dev) is available on the #dojo channel over on freenode irc, that is if nobody else can give you an answer.